# How can I display the xAxes and yAxes data in the tooltip, Chart JS?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to achieve the Tooltip shown below in the first image. Inside of the tooltip I need to display the `yAxes` and `xAxes` data. The chart.js version I am using is 3.7.0

My tooltip looks like this:

[image]

The tooltip that I am trying copy:

[image]

The chart.js documentation is quite hard for me to understand. Is there any guru that can explain to me.

**Question**: Why is my tooltip returning the `yAxes` data, that I return as a variable(`label`) as undefined?

Are there any other options I can use to make my chart look like the chart in the second picture?

**My Code**:

```
 tooltip: {
   displayColors: false,
   backgroundColor: 'rgba(45,132,180,0.8)',
   bodyFontColor: 'rgb(255,255,255)',
   callbacks: {
     title: function(item, everything){
       return;
     },
     label: function(item, everything){
       //console.log(item);
       //console.log(everything);

       let first = item.yLabel;
       let second = item.xLabel;

       let label = first + ' ppm';
       return label;
     }
   }
 }
```

Thank you in advance for your time and efforts, please help me figure out what am I doing wrong!

Comment: I don't see a problem with what you're doing. I plugged your callback functions into a chart I made, and the tooltip showed the expected value, e.g. `1.225 ppm`. Perhaps you could edit your question and show more of your code, including your entire Chart constructor call, any code populating your dataset, etc.

Comment: @Marion that is because you are using V2 of chart.js which is outdated and not supported anymore, if you try to do it in the latest version it wont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yLabel` and `xLabel` dont exist anymore on the tooltip, they are V2 syntax.
You can just axess the y object in the parsed section to get the y value. Then you can use the `afterBody` callback to show the x label like so:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderColor: 'pink'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        displayColors: false,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(45,132,180,0.8)',
        bodyFontColor: 'rgb(255,255,255)',
        callbacks: {
          title: () => {
            return
          },
          label: (ttItem) => (`${ttItem.parsed.y} ppm`),
          afterBody: (ttItems) => (ttItems[0].label)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hello @LeeLenalee, I appreciate your effort and your code works like a charm.

Comment: Question is: Is there a way or perhaps How can I display a different set of labels in afterbody?
And secondly: In the second picture I attatched, the tooltip has a different style. I read on documentation about `custom` or `external` tooltips, but It was a complete frustration trying to understand the `chart.js 3.7.0` documentation about `external` tooltips. Could you perhaps help me style my `tooltip` to make it look like the one in the second picture?
Once again thanks in advance.

Comment: Here are 2 fiddles that show you how to implement a basic external tooltip: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/xhrs2wvc/19/
https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/qb17Lx4j/7/

Comment: Can I use a different `label` variable in the xAxes of `tooltip` but maintain the part where indexes are connected between the yAxes and the new and different label I want to add on xAxes?

Comment: Can you please contact me at this email: jameulukasli1@gmail.com . This project is for my university, and its due to monday, if you could contact me and help me complete it. That would be great. (the chart has some other minor problems that I cant figure out, please help!).

Comment: I tried implementing your code but on hover the tooltip isnt being displayed and Im left with [this](https://ibb.co/kK4P2Py) error in browser.